CORS Error with Traefik, Cloudflare and .Net API
I get CORS problem when accessing my API, which is part of my docker-compose full-stack app. I've struggled to get it to work for quite some time and I was hoping to get some guidance in where I might be confused. I've swapped my domain with my.domain, but otherwise the code is identical.
I'm using cloudflare, and the frontend is accessible at my.domain. But all requests yield a CORS error.
As a final note, this is my first try at a full-stack app, so the frameworks may not be optimal, the choice was based on where had the most previous knowledge/interest to learn more about. But, I still appreciate any shared opinions on these choices.
docker-compose
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v3.1
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80" # Define HTTP entry point
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443" # Define HTTPS entry point
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The HTTPS port
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - encrypt:/encrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      api-inventory:
        condition: service_started
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.Development
    restart: always
    command: "npm run dev"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/app/src:readonly
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_POLLING=true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`my.domain`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api-inventory.entrypoints=web"

  api-inventory:
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.Development
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
    volumes:
      - ./backend/inventory:/api/inventory/src:readonly
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - DB_HOST=${POST_HOST}
      - DB_NAME=${POST_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${POST_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${POST_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend

Program.cs (CORS Setup in .net API)
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://my.domain", "http://my.domain") 
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowCredentials(); // Allow credentials if needed (e.g., cookies)
        });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

fetch request made from frontend component
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8090/api/User");
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }
      return response.json();

My expectation is to just get the frontend to be able to send requests to the backend and recieve response, full CRUD.
My understanding was that I could communicate within the docker-container, not requiring CORS. Although, when using the domain I realize this may no longer be the case. If this is possible with some alterations, please let me know.
Else, any directions for a good article, video, or tips for how to setup the required solution is appreciated.
